# Can't save notebook. Save Dialogue opens "Stylesheet Dialogue" instead

Tags: bugs, notebooks

I tried both <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> as well as File->Save. But this both produces the dialogue shown below. Save As opens a new empty notebook.

**Why does this happen and how do I fix it?**

[image]

Comment: Do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until someone else confirms the behavior you have seen.

Comment: It was reported already but afaik the only advice is to restart MMA and it will be gone, for some time.

Comment: As @Kuba suggested, are you able to confirm that restarting Mathematica fixed the issue? I'm reporting this internally (Wolfram) and this information will be useful

Comment: Yes, closing the application (which allowed me to finally save it) and restarting cleared this issue.

Comment: This kind of thing happens to me as well from time to time. In my case, it is usually the `Drawing Tools` pop-up that keeps coming up when I try to save the notebook. I have noticed that if I try to continue the session, I get an error message about an inconsistent internal state. My usual reaction is to quit the notebook, and then choose the save the changes at the prompt before the notebook closes.

Comment: This is what happened to me as well in 12.2 on Windows 10. Ctrl+s opens a new Function Resource Notebook. Ctrl+Shift+S opens a new data resource notebook. Whew! I thought it was a _me_ problem.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I was just making some graphs and suddenly I cannot save the file unless I choose one of these styles I don't want.

Comment: @Yu Chao, you can try the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I met this for several times before.
I've been convinced that this is a bug.

To fix this without restart, try execute `FrontEndTokenExecute@"Save"`.